# Can we change the color of the region around the plot using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to replicate a graph from excel in R. For that I have to create a graph in which all the border region of a graph is colored as shown below:

[image]

I tried many ways and also searched alot but it yielded no result.

This is the best I have reached in replicating the graph:
[image]

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "border region"? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd like to change the theme of your ggplot. Lots of options [under the hood](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html). Here's a basic example to do what you're describing:

```
set.seed(42)
example <- data.frame(x = 1:100, value = rnorm(100))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(example, aes(x, value)) + 
  geom_line() +

  # here's where we set the appearance of the theme
  #  For more:  https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray75"), # region outside plot
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), # region inside plot
        panel.grid = element_line(color = "gray90"))     # bring back gridlines
```

[image]